# SQL Group by and update/delete row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL.Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stack_Example](
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Product_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Stack_Example] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

With data like shown under:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Stack_Example] ([ID], [Product_ID], [Quantity], [Price]) VALUES (1, 25, CAST(55.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Stack_Example] ([ID], [Product_ID], [Quantity], [Price]) VALUES (2, 25, CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Stack_Example] ([ID], [Product_ID], [Quantity], [Price]) VALUES (3, 26, CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
GO
```

So my problem here is i need to group those items by Price, Product_Id and SUM(Quantity).

There is need for Update/Delete query assuming my output window need to looks like

[image]

Its simple when you do a select query

```
select Product_ID,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity,Price from Stack_Example
Group by Product_ID,Price
```

So at very begin what i need to do is to delete the row with id : 2 And update the row with id 1 set Quantity = Quantity + 1 ( Quantity of deleted row ).

So when i run the select query without grouping and summing i need to get the same output

```
UPDATE Stack_Example SET Quantity = (SELECT SUM(Quantity)
                                    FROM Stack_Example child 
                                    WHERE child.Product_ID = Stack_Example.Product_ID
                                    GROUP BY Product_ID)

DELETE FROM Stack_Example WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                                        FROM Stack_Example 
                                        WHERE Product_Id IN ( (SELECT TOP 1 Product_ID 
                                                                    FROM Stack_Example
                                                                    GROUP BY Product_ID 
                                                                    HAVING COUNT(Product_ID)>1)))
```

Comment: Sorry I can't clearly understand what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

First update your table with total amount of products with same price

```
with cte as (
    select
        Product_ID, Price, Quantity = sum(Quantity) 
    from
        Stack_Example
    group by Product_ID, Price
)

update s
set s.Quantity = c.Quantity
from
    Stack_Example s
    join cte c on s.Product_ID = c.Product_ID and s.Price = c.Price
```

Then run another script to delete duplicate rows

```
with cte as (
    select
        *, row_number() over (partition by Product_ID, Price order by Product_ID) rn
    from
        Stack_Example
)

delete from cte where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear - but couldn't you just create a view with the aggrgates?

Anyhow.....
Not sure why you would do this but...you could insert the aggregated values and then delete the older ones....as per below.

```
DECLARE @MaxId INT;
DECLARE @ProductId = 25;


--GET THE MAX ID OF PRODUCT IN QUESTION
SELECT @MaxId = MAX(ID) FROM Stack_Example WHERE Product_Id = @ProductId;


--INSERT THE AGGREGATE VALUES INTO TABLE
INSERT INTO Stack_Example
  SELECT @MaxId + 1, @ProductId, Price, SUM(Quantity)
  FROM Stack_Example
  WHERE 
    Product_Id = @ProductId
  GROUP BY 
    @MaxId + 1, [Product_ID], [Price];

--DELETE THE PRE-AGGREGATE VALUES
DELETE FROM Stack_Example WHERE ProductId = @ProductId and Id <= @MaxId;
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. If you take a look on my code which as propose as an answer it may help you to understand me. 

The major issue in my code is that it works only if there is 2 rows per same item. If i add three rows with same Product_Id it wont make me a delete because i get TOP 1

Comment: Why don't you just use a view?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used aggregates and additional temporary table to achieve that:

```
--group records and insert them into temporary table
select distinct
     Min(id) over (partition by product_id, price) [ID],
     Product_id,
     sum(Quantity) over (partition by product_id, price) [Quantity],
     Price
into #new_stack_example
from #Stack_Example

--delete old values
delete #Stack_example

--insert new values
insert into #Stack_example
select * from #new_stack_example
```

First `SELECT` statement reflects your logic:

> So my problem here is i need to group those items by Price, Product_Id and SUM(Quantity).

But instead of grouping, I use window functions and then select distinct records.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    UPDATE Stack_Example SET Quantity = a.Quantity
    from ( select Product_ID,sum(Quantity) Quantity  
    from Stack_Example Group by Product_ID) a
    where   Stack_Example.Product_ID=a.Product_ID   

    ;with cte as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by product_id order by product_id) rn 
    from Stack_Example)

    delete from cte where rn > 1
```